# How To Scrape Content From a Website That Requests a Metamask Connection

Tags: python, web-scraping, blockchain, ethereum, imacros

We want to scrape content from pages like this one:
https://dxsale.app/app/pages/defipresale?saleID=1000&chain=BSC

It has content from Binance Smart Chain (BSC) projects and in order to see it, the site is requesting a Metamask connection with the BSC MainNet.
If you access the Metamask connection without it(the BSC MainNet), you get "No connected web3 wallet detected!"

> A quick parenthesis on Metamask and how to set it up for BSC Mainnet:
> https://metamask.io/download.html (Available in Chrome, Firefox, Brave and Edge.)
> https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/connecting-metamask-to-binance-smart-chain

BTW I don't know if this is possible, but when the site is loading it says that is getting data from the blockchain. The platform is being used to launch decentralized projects. If the project's data is stored on the blockchain it probably should be openly available for everyone.

Here is the platform ETH address:
https://etherscan.io/address/0xf063fe1ab7a291c5d06a86e14730b00bf24cb589#code
Below the main contract is a section of the Contract ABI, probably related to the project's creation.

So how can we get the data? There are almost 1500 pages/projects right now.

Comment: Hum, OK, sounds "interesting" but what is the Pb with iMacros...? (No Script posted...)  The 'etherscan' Site looks pretty straightforward to extract/scrape to me, from a quick look... I didn't come further than "Connect Wallet to start" on the 'dxsale' Site, but I didn't go through the 'Metamask' Setup Procedure... If you go for iMacros, open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum I would say, as this won't be an "easy" Q/A Thread for 'SO'..., and I won't be writing your Script, ah-ah...! (Read my Profile for more Info...)